# <h:outputText> rendered the old value even after ajax update

Tags: jsf, facelets

In below code, I click the Submit button. That change `boolean` `result` value to `true` in `backing_home` bean via a `ajax` call.

If I remove the rendered `rendered="#{backing_home.result}"`, I see the updated output properly.
But with the below code it is `false`. I think it doesn't render the new value

```
<h:commandButton id="MySubmit" value="Submit" action="#{backing_home.toggleRenderResult}">
   <f:ajax render=":AjaxGuess:result2"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:outputText id="result2" value="#{backing_home.result}" rendered="#{backing_home.result}" />
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: this is a common mistake, you should include the outputText in a panelGroup and update the panelGroup instead...

Comment: @Hatem Alimam May I know why?

Comment: Because if the value is false the outputText won't be present, and if it's not present it can be updated even if the value is true. So you have to have an always present element to update which is the panelGroup.

Comment: @HatemAlimam Grate explain. Thank you. I got it. Very logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update the code as below based on Hatem Alimam's comment.

```
<h:commandButton id="MySubmit" value="Submit" action="#{backing_home.toggleRenderResult}">
   <f:ajax render=":AjaxGuess:result2"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="result2">
  <h:outputText value="#{backing_home.result}" rendered="#{backing_home.result}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```